# Call Amplify.configure() before using any methods on the category. | SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, graphql, aws-amplify

When I start my project I got this error. How can I fix this problem. I am trying to use Graphql without Apollo SDK.

**Error:**

Failed to initialize Amplify with ConfigurationError: AWSS3StoragePlugin.AWSS3StoragePlugin cannot be added after `Amplify.configure()`.
Recovery suggestion: Do not add plugins after calling `Amplify.configure()`.
/Users/ufukkosker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArtApp-xxxxxxxhzyxxxxx/SourcePackages/checkouts/amplify-swift/Amplify/Categories/DataStore/DataStoreCategory.swift:21: Fatal error: DataStore category is not configured. Call Amplify.configure() before using any methods on the category.

**ArtApp:**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AWSS3StoragePlugin

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        let storagePlugin = AWSS3StoragePlugin()
         do {
             try Amplify.add(plugin: storagePlugin)
             try Amplify.configure()
           print("Amplify configured with storage plugin")
          } catch {
            print("Failed to initialize Amplify with \(error)")
          }
        return true
    }
}


@main
struct ArtApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**AmplifyDataStoreConfig:**

```
import Amplify
import AWSS3StoragePlugin

final class AmplifyDataStoreConfig {
    static var shared = AmplifyDataStoreConfig()
    
    private init() {
       
    }
    
    func fetchArttist() async {
        do {
            let items = try await Amplify.DataStore.query(Artist.self)
            for item in items {
                print("artist id: \(item.id)")
            }
        } catch let error as DataStoreError {
            print("Error querying items: \(error)")
        } catch {
            print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**LaunchView:**

```
struct LaunchView: View {
    @State var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @State var isPresent: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.artOrangeLight)
                    .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                    .offset(y: isAnimating ? .zero : -UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .animation(.spring().delay(0.5), value: isAnimating)
                Text("art")
                    .foregroundColor(.artieLogoText)
                    .font(.custom(.gothamLight, size: 90))
                    .offset(y: isAnimating ? .zero : -UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .animation(.spring().delay(1), value: isAnimating)
            }
            Text("ie")
                .foregroundColor(.artLogoText)
                .font(.custom(.gothamLight, size: 90))
                .offset(x: isAnimating ? .zero : UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .animation(.spring().delay(1.5), value: isAnimating)
        }
        .onAppear{
            isAnimating = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                isPresent = true
            }
            

            Task {
                await AmplifyDataStoreConfig.shared.fetchArttist()
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresent) {
            OnboardingView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if are correctly configured  `awsconfiguration.json` and `amplifyconfiguration.json` files.
In my case `awsconfiguration` file was incorrect, and it crashed the app